Designing long running transactions
I have to conduct tasks 1-6 in an orchestrated async manner. every task has a receive queue and respond queue. These tasks are long-running...can take several days to finish.
The orchestrator is listening on respond queues and making decisions to send message to the next tasks receive queue.
each task is a rest service call to an external system , receives results and runs some rules to calculate outcome.
Orchestrator{
Task1
Task2
Task3
Task4
Task5
Task6
Success
}
Since every tasks happens in an order...this works.
However, i might have a situation that some tasks  can happen in parallel . And if those parallel tasks all succeed then i can proceed to success
Orchestrator{
Task1
Task2
Task3
(Upon completion of Task 3. Task 4,5,6 need to execute in parallel)
Task4 Task5 Task6
Success
}
Is there some open source framework to write this ? i currently use a spring boot based stack.
What's the best way of handling situation like this : some tasks in order and some in parallel . message queues for ordered tasks and a pub/sub for parallel tasks ? what's the best way to aggregate parallel task results (which also can take a while since this is a long running SAGA) ?
Any help would appreciated.
